# Dynamic query Django build

Tags: django, dynamic, django-queryset

**create dynamic query set using Django query**

this case performs "AND" operation. but some time value is blank or NULL.

example:- user model have name, age, and city three columns.
and perform operation filter but this and query is dynamic some time 3 fields available or sometimes one or maybe two how to write a dynamic query.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Q()`

```
from django.db.models import Q
query = Q()
if need_filter_name:
    query &= Q(name='my_name')
if need_filter_age:
    query &= Q(age='my_age')
if need_filter_city:
    query &= Q(city='my_city')

User.objects.filter(query)
```

If you need `OR` operator use `query |= Q()`
For `AND` operator use `query &= Q()`

Comment: thanks, but 'Q' use for OR query I have use AND operations.